# I am inserting data from multiple tbls into one and I want the last columns to be DBName so I know where it originated from. How do I do that?

Tags: sql

I am creating the table below and for the BOTName, I want to insert the name the of the DB where the Data came from.  I have no problem inserting the actual data, just trying to figure out how to custom label the rows so I know where the data originated.

Create Table #temp1
(
ID Integer,
RunDate DateTime,
BOTName TEXT
)

Just googled a bunch, but I could not find anything specific to my ask.

Comment: you don't share enough about how you are doing this but you could hard-code the BOTName for each source.  inserrt into #temp1 values(........, 'Source #1')

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your particular syntax, but if you're using TSQL you could simply add the value `DB_NAME()` to your insert statement

```
INSERT INTO #temp1 (ID, RunDate, BOTName) VALUES
(1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, DB_NAME())
```

DB_NAME() returns the current database context:

```
USE master;
SELECT DB_NAME()
```

returns 'master'

Also it might be worth pointing out the the TEXT data type is depreciated and you should use NVARCHAR(x) instead:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Thank you for the tip on TEXT.  One more question, if I want to return the Tbl the data came from instead of the DB name, how would that look?

Comment: You can't. You'd need to add that as a column and pass the hard coded table name.